# How to take an mp3 file as input from user in React or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fs, google-speech-to-text-api

So I wanted to take MP3 file as input from user and then I wanted to convert it into base64 string.
I was able to take input using the `<input type="file">` tag but when I try to use 'fs' for converting it into base64 string I get an error :

```
error - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL.
```

I basically want to take an input file MP3 as input from user and then use Google Speech-To-Text Api to convert it into text.

Heres my front-end code :

```
import React, {useEffect,Component} from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import axios from 'axios';

class Home extends Component {

  state = {

    selectedFile:null

  }

  onFileChange = event => {
    
      // Update the state
      this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
    };

   onFileUpload = async () => {

        let res = await axios.post('/api/backend',this.state.selectedFile);
        console.log("response is ",res);
  
    }

  render()
  {

    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Head>
          <title>Text to speech</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>

  
        <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
                  <button onClick={this.onFileUpload}>
                    Upload!
                  </button>
              </div>
              </div>

    )
  }

};

export default Home;
```

Backend.js:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library

import speech from '@google-cloud/speech'
const fs = require('fs');

export default async function Speech(req,res) {

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
 const filename = req.body.name;
 const encoding = 'MP3';
 const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
 const languageCode = 'az-AZ';

const config = {
  encoding: encoding,
  sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
  languageCode: languageCode,
};

/**
 * Note that transcription is limited to 60 seconds audio.
 * Use a GCS file for audio longer than 1 minute.
 */
const audio = {
  content: fs.readFileSync(filename).toString('base64'),
};

const request = {
  config: config,
  audio: audio,
};

// Detects speech in the audio file. This creates a recognition job that you
// can wait for now, or get its result later.
const [operation] =  await client.longRunningRecognize(request);

// Get a Promise representation of the final result of the job
const [response] = await operation.promise();
const transcription = response.results
  .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
  .join('\n');

  res.status(200).json(transcription)
}
```

Comment: Use a `FormData` instance to upload the file from the client. On the backend, if you're using Express I recommend [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Comment: I tried your back end code and it works for me when I hard coded a full path of a MP3 for `filename`. 1.) What is the value of your `filename`? 2.) If you do `console.log(typeof(filename));` what data type does it return?